# Getting collection of most general type from a GenericType<T>.class filter

Tags: java, generics

I apologize in advance for the terrible title, suggestions for improvement are eagerly accepted.

Let's say I have a method which filters a `List<T>` of arbitrary type based on a `class`, returning a new `List` whose elements are those of the input list that are instances of the given class. Here's a straightforward implementation (yes, you can also do it in a 1-liner with streams):

```
public static <T> List<T> filterByClass(List<?> list, Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : list) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(o)) {
            filtered.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

This works great if you pass it a list of a non-generic type like `String` as in (prints `foo bar`):

```
List<Object> l = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, "foo ", 2, "bar ");
filterByClass(l, String.class).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now I want to pass to filter on a class of a generic type, say `Optional<T>`:

```
List<Object> l = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, Optional.of("foo"), 2, Optional.of("bar"));
filterByClass(l, Optional.class).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

That works fine and prints:

```
Optional[foo]
Optional[bar]
```

The problem is there is a raw type hidden there. The return type of the `filterByClass` call above is `List<Optional>`, not `List<Optional<...>>`. Many uses will trigger warnings about raw types, etc.

Now I understand type erasure, and I know that a `class` object will never [carry generic type information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437897/149138) - there is no such `Optional<String>.class` or `Optional<Integer>.class` - there is only `Optional.class`.

However, there is still a better return value than the raw type: I would like instead the fully-generic wildcard version: `List<Optional<?>>`. This should be totally type safe, since any `Optional` is an `Optional<?>`, right?

Assignment doesn't work, since `List<Optional>` is not convertible to `List<Optional<?>>`

```
List<Optional<?>> r = filterByClass(l, Optional.class);
```

A cast doesn't work either because the types aren't even castable (in the same way that `Foo<T>` can never be directly cast to `Foo<U>` no matter the relationship between different types `T` and `U`).

The only solution seems to be to cast all the way down to a raw `List` and then back up to the list with wildcard-paramaterized type-parameter:

```
List<Optional<?>> r = (List)filterByClass(l, Optional.class);
```

Now obviously such casts aren't safe in the general case, and this would be totally unsafe if the type parameter in the assignment `Optional<?>` didn't match the `class` object passed to `filterByClass` - although [I think they are safe in the specific case that the `class` matches the type parameter with unbounded wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47660823/149138).

Is there some way to do this without the potentially unsafe casts, either by changing the `filterByClass` method or some safe casting of the result?

Another possible answer would be that this is not safe (i.e., the result of `filterByClass(..., Optional.class)` cannot safely be converted to `List<Optional<?>>`, so the question is ill-formed.

Comment: In the case of an `Optional<T>`, do you consider `Optional.empty()` to be an instance of `Optional<T>` or not?

Comment: You can supply a `Function<Object, T>` to the filter method, which returns a casted reference if it is an instance, or null. In the case of `Optional<T>`, `List<T>` etc, you'd have to find some way to determine if it is safe to cast, e.g. `!opt.isPresent() || opt.get() instanceof Whatever`.

Comment: @AndyTurner - yes, I think `Optional.empty()` is an `Optional<U>` for any U. About your suggestion though, I'm not interesting in "looking into" the type `T` here: I just want to get a `List<T<?>>` since for a generic type `Foo<T>` I think it is always safe to cast to `Foo<?>` (and hence the raw type `Foo` can be safely case to `Foo<?>`). I'll live with having an unbounded wildcard in my type.

Answer (score 4):

You could change the signature of `filterByClass` to:

```
public static <T> List<T> filterByClass(List<?> list, Class<? extends T> clazz) {...}
```

Then you can have `T` be inferred from the assignee:

```
List<Object> l = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, Optional.of("foo"), 2, Optional.of("bar"));
List<Optional<?>> result = filterByClass(l, Optional.class);
```

This works since a raw `Optional` is assignable to `Optional<?>` (which is safe), so `Class<Optional>` satisfies `Class<? extends Optional<?>>`, and you can add the `Optional` returned by `cast` to the list of `Optional<?>`.

Comment: That's the trick! Bonus question: this works if I let `T` be inferred as you suggested, but I always thought that was just a shortcut and I could explicitly specify the function type parameter if I wanted. However if I change your last line to  `List<Optional<?>> result = Class.<Optional<?>>filterByClass(l, Optional.class);` it fails to compile (complaining that `Optional.class` doesn't match `Class<? extends Optional<?>>`). What's up with that? Is there any type parameter I can use, or is type inference doing something "magic" here? Note `Class` is the class this function appears in.

Comment: Hmm, I say that but `javac` doesn't really seem to like it: https://ideone.com/SDmtSS Incidentally the 2 lines of test code I used/posted only work in eclipse. Adding an explicit type hint of `<Optional<?>>` also breaks the example. I'll wiki this answer so people can still see the suggestion. ( @BeeOnRope Looks like I didn't test enough, this seems to be an eclipse peculiarity)

Comment: This `javac` vs Eclipse discrepancy was interesting enough that I [asked over here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662493/149138). I'm guessing `javac` is right here since some tests with the same conversion (without argument or return type inference) also fail on eclipse. In general it doesn't seem legal to convert a `P1<P2>` to a `P1<? extends P2<?>>`, but let's hope some language lawyer types weigh in to confirm.