# Eclipse ECJ accepts this code, javac doesn't - who is right?

Tags: java, eclipse, language-lawyer, javac

Consider the following `returnsNull` function and a call to it with a generic type:

```
public static <T> List<T> returnNull(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    return null;
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    List<AtomicReference<?>> l = returnNull(AtomicReference.class);
}
```

The Eclipse compiler, when set to Java 8, accepts it, but `javac` in Java 8 rejects it with:

```
incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference<?>>)
```

The underlying difference seems to be that given a two parameterized types `P1<T>` and `P2<T>`, Eclipse allows conversion from the outer type parameterized with the raw inner type: `P1<P2>` to the outer type parameterized with a lower bound of the of the inner-type with an unbounded wildcard like `P1<? extends P2<?>>`. `javac` doesn't.

This isn't just a theoretical musing: if this code was accepted it would solve my [generics filtering problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661658/149138).

**Who is right?**

Comment: This kind of thing (or maybe it's just one thing, I don't know) is a longstanding issue with ECJ.  See e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397317.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - well the comment thread on that bug indicates that it was actually a problem in `javac` and that it was fixed in Java 7, so it seems like that case wasn't an issue in ECJ?

Comment: Oh maybe it's that way round, then :)  I'm not sure, to be honest, just a thing I was vaguely aware of.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't see any connection to bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397317 neither by content nor by the history of which version of javac accepts/rejects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**During [applicability inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1)** ECJ infers `<T>` to `AtomicReference#RAW`, which let's the signature of `returnNull` appear as

```
List<AtomicReference#RAW> returnNull(Class<? extends AtomicReference#RAW>)
```

The exact steps being:

- [initial constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1):

  - `⟨Class<AtomicReference#RAW> → Class<? extends T#0>⟩`
- [reduced to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2):

  - `⟨Class<AtomicReference#RAW> <: Class<? extends T#0>⟩`
  - `⟨AtomicReference#RAW <= ? extends T#0⟩`
  - `⟨AtomicReference#RAW <: T#0⟩`
  - `AtomicReference#RAW <: T#0`
- [resolved to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4):

  - `T#0 = AtomicReference#RAW`

Now, there's no problem passing a value of type `Class<AtomicReference#RAW>` into that method.

(*the suffix #RAW is an implementation specific denotation for raw types, reproduced here for clarity*).

**EDIT:** Things look different during **[invocation type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2)**: By adding the target type into the mix we end up (during [incorporation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.3)) with the following constraint:

- `⟨AtomicReference#RAW <: AtomicReference<?>⟩`

This constraint should reduce to FALSE, but ecj reduces to TRUE. From this, rejecting the program seems to be the correct answer.

I filed [bug 528970](https://bugs.eclipse.org/528970) for further investigation in ECJ.

There is some irony in this, because [javac has a long standing bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8026527) whereby it wrongly assumes `T#RAW <: T<X>`. For compatibility reasons, ECJ explicitly copied this bug into many locations, but apparently in one particular code location it's the opposite: javac applies subtyping where ECJ checks for compatibility.

**EDIT 2:** One year later it seems that the bug in ECJ can only be fixed after JLS has been improved in and around [JDK-8054721](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054721).

Comment: Shouldn't ECJ reject the assignment then? As it also rejects the following: `List<AtomicReference> l1 = null; List<AtomicReference<?>> l2 = l1;`. And maybe this is just a discrepancy, but [eclipse shows `T` is inferred to `AtomicReference<?>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkT8A.png).