# Java cannot cast from list of raw generic type to list of wildcard generic type

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

Here's a quick little generic class to make this question easier to understand. You can pretend it "boxes" a value if you want.

```
public class Box<T> {    }
```

---

### Question

Now, in my `main` method, I can have this:

```
Box b1 = new Box<>();
Box<?> b2 = b1;
Box b3 = b2;
```

So it's quite clear to me that a raw `Box` and a `Box` parameterized with a wildcard can both be casted to each others' types.

```
Object box = (Box<?>)(Box) (Box<?>)(Box) ... new Box<>();// Valid (without the ellipsis)
```

So **why** is it that my `List` of raw boxes can't be cast to a `List` of wildcard boxes, and vice versa? (Any documentation that is responsible for the compiling error the following code raises, would do if you can find it.)

```
List<Box> rawBoxes = new LinkedList<>();
List<Box<?>> wildcardBoxes = new LinkedList<>();

Object o1 = (List<Box<?>>) rawBoxes;// Cannot cast from List<Box> to List<Box<?>>
Object o2 = (List<Box>) wildcardBoxes;// Cannot cast from List<Box<?>> to List<Box>
```

"Cannot cast from `List<Box>` to `List<Box<?>>`" and vice versa...

---

### Before you answer/mark as dupe...

I'm guessing that someone is going to try and bring up the fact that a `List<Dog>` can't be cast to a `List<Animal>` and vice versa. The reason for that, however, is:

```
List<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<>();
animals.add(new Cat());

Dog dog = ((List<Dog>) animals).get(0);
```

A list of `Dog`s is **not** a list of `Animal`s, because it can only contain `Dog`s.

With a `List<Box>` and `List<Box<?>>`, any sort of `Box` can be put into either:

```
List<Box> rawBoxes = new LinkedList<>();
List<Box<?>> wildcardBoxes = new LinkedList<>();

Box rawBox = new Box<>();
Box<?> wildcardBox = new Box<>();
Box<String> stringBox = new Box<>();

// They can both take raw boxes
rawBoxes.add(rawBox);
wildcardBoxes.add(rawBox);

// They can both take wildcard boxes
rawBoxes.add(wildcardBox);
wildcardBoxes.add(wildcardBox);

// They can both take boxes storing arbitrary stuff
rawBoxes.add(stringBox);
wildcardBoxes.add(stringBox);
```

---

### Lastly

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660823/is-it-safe-to-cast-from-listoptional-to-listoptional) came up, which tells me that such a cast would be safe, if Java were to allow it. What I want to know is **why a cast from `List<Box>` to `List<Box<?>>` isn't allowed** and **how to get a `List<Box<?>>` off of a `List<Box>`.**

If there's another question that will thoroughly answer both of these things, please mark this as a duplicate. I didn't know exactly what to look up when searching for an answer myself.

Comment: *Don't* use raw generics. --- If you insist, cast through a full raw: `(List<Box<?>>) (List) rawBoxes`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for that comment. I was hoping that there was a way to cast without having to use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` to get rid of warnings (because those kinda peeve me), but I'll definitely stick with that if nothing else comes up. The reason I needed this is because the `getClass()` method I'm calling returns a `Class<? extends RawType>` (or something similar) in my code, so I'm stuck with that raw type. :(

Comment: `Box<?>` is not the same as `Box`. Even though *they* are assignment compatible, they are different, so `List<Box<?>>` is entire different from `List<Box>` and are *not* assignment compatible. See [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas I had actually used the types in that question as inspiration for the second part of my answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766704/cannot-convert-from-listlist-to-listlist) link helps explain the problem of my question with specifics from the documentation however. It makes much more sense to think about `Box<?>` and `Box` being very different types however. Thanks.